# What font uses \documentclass[german]{ecv}?

Tags: fonts, letters, ecv

What font is used in my CV? How can I look up the default font used in a document? See the sample below. How can I set that font to be used in scrlttr2?

```
\documentclass[%
  fontsize=12pt, % Schriftgröße
  version=last%  % Neueste Version von KOMA-Skript verwenden
]{scrlttr2}
```

CV:

```
    \documentclass[german]{ecv}

\ecvName{Frieder Nikolaisen}


\begin{document}
    
    
    
    \begin{ecv}
        
        %%% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
        %%% Person
        %%% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
        \bigskip
        
        \ecvSec{\hypertarget{hypertarget:\ecvPerson}{\ecvPerson}}
        
        \ecvEPR{Name}   {Test, Nobody}  
        
        
    \end{ecv}
    

    
    
\end{document}
%\end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `pdffonts` on the template in the documentation shows

```bash
> pdffonts /usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/doc/latex/ecv/template/CV-template_de.pdf
name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
LCEJLX+NimbusSanL-Regu               Type 1            Custom           yes yes no      15  0
YLHMNN+CMMI10                        Type 1            Custom           yes yes no      21  0
SYYANF+CMSY10                        Type 1            Custom           yes yes no      24  0
PBWWGV+NimbusSanL-Bold               Type 1            Custom           yes yes no      27  0
SDAWEK+NimbusSanL-ReguItal
```

which points to `\usepackage{helvet}` and, indeed, at line 72 of `ecv.cls` we see

```
\RequirePackage{helvet}
```

It is the Helvetica clone available in the standard TeX distributions.